# Microsoft Graph - Embedding Online Meetings in iFrame

Tags: iframe, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to embedding an Online Meeting URL (obtained by Graph API) in an iFrame (that shows up un a webpage of my website). Here I try to show you more details of the issue that i'm facing.

--> [Platform Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFFGd.png)

The platform selection seems to be ok, I can choose between Teams client or Browser, but when I select "browser" an error shows up.

--> [Error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPYfB.png)

I guess if there are limitations in the use of Online Meetings in iFrame or did someone already find a workaround about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: One should never ever post an error message in an image. It must be a text format that is easy to analyze and read.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in this case it's not easy format the error in a nice way, that gives the same "feel" as the browser console does.

Answer (score 0):

@Alessandro Nicoli:
You cannot embed the Teams meeting UI in your website. Every teams meeting should either be opened inside Teams app or in Teams browser.
Currently embedding Teams meetings or chats in a webpage is not possible.